# Passing variables into sed c\ block

Tags: regex, sed

Is it possible to pass variables between the matching part of a sed script into the text I'm using to replace with the "change" command c/ ?

```
:t
$!{
    /OBJECT/,/\<End\>/ {
        /\<End\>/!{
            N;
            bt
        }
    }
    /Num\s*\(\-\?[0-9]\)\+\nID\s*\([0-9]\)\nName\s*Old Name~/ c\
OBJECT\
Num            \1\
ID             \2\
Name           New Name~\
End
}
```

I'm executing this file with:

```
sed -i -f name.sed OldNames.txt
```

Data from the original file is in the format:

```
OBJECT
Num       0
ID        1
Name      Name1
End

OBJECT
Num       1
ID        2
Name      Name2
End
```

The regex matching is working perfectly, but I'd like to take the variables \1 and \2 and use them in the change block. Right now I'm just getting the actual output "\1" and "\2" where I've used those references.

Comment: Show us a bit of data

Comment: Since you want to perform a substitution with backreferences, why don't you use the substitution command `s///` instead of `c`?

Comment: I was hoping to use `c` for convenience. I've truncated the sample data a lot. While I want to match and retain values from the first few lines, I want to do a large replace of a majority of the lines (about 50 or so per OBJECT/End block. `c` looked like the simplest way to achieve that. If backreferencing is not possible, however, I may have to resort to `s///` .

Comment: You've gone WAY off the rails. sed is for s/old/new, that is all. By trying to do anything else you're using constructs that became obsolete in the mid 1980s when awk was invented. Whatever it is you're trying to do will be vastly simpler, clearer, more efficient, and more portable using awk. Show us the expected output given your posted sample input and tag your question with `awk` for help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ed. It appears the answer to my question of if `c` allows backreferencing is no which is informative. With some rethinking I was able to solve my problem today by just using multiple `s///` lines instead of trying to replace the entire block of matched text with `c`.

Comment: @tm6391 - you are right, the answer is no.  Your solution of `s///` followed by `c` or `a` for addition of large preformatted sections makes sense.   It is also worth looking at using `r` to simply read in a separate preformatted file, or, in GNU sed, `e`.